# maximization of trace between two operators with respect to different norm constraints

Tags: mathematics, quantum-operation, information-theory, optimization, trace-distance

I want to maximize $\text{Tr}(XY)$ over $X$ for fixed $Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are both hermitian (but doesn't necessarily positive) operators, and $X$ is constrained by its p-norm bounded by $1$, i.e. $|X|_p \leq 1$. I want to prove that optimized operators, the one when the norm constraint is $p=1$ and the other one when $p=2$, are related to each other.

Update: My question turns out to be very misleading, so please ignore the q! Apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Isn't $\vert X_{opt,2}\vert_2 = 1$ without the factor of $\sqrt{d}$? That is, if $X_{opt,p}$ is a rank-1 projection onto $Y$'s maximum eigenvalue (I assume finite-dimensional), then $\vert X_{opt,p}\vert_p=1$ for all $p$, right? And it will saturate the bound you found, which seems to apply for all $p$ as well.

Comment: @SamJaques $|X_{opt,2}|_2$ is 1. Since $max \text{Tr}(XY) = |X|_1 |Y|_\infty \leq \sqrt{d} |X|_2  |Y|_\infty$ (now, just for general $X$, and using $|X|_2 \leq \sqrt{d}|X|_1$ inequaility), if we optimize with $p=2$-norm constraint, we end up getting $\sqrt{d} |X_{opt,2}|_2  |Y|_\infty = \sqrt{d} |Y|_\infty$. Does this make senes? I could be entirely wrong though! that's why I want discussions in the forum

Comment: @SamJaques Now I think about it again, and I think $X_{opt,p}$ should not be always rank-1 projection onto $Y$'s maximum eigenvalue. Rather, $X_{opt,p}$ can be a sum of projections to + eigenspace of $Y$ and - eigenspace of $Y$ with -1 factor, then divide by 2, i.e. $X_{opt,p} = \frac{|Y+><Y+| - |Y-><Y-|}{2}$ where $|Y+>, |Y->$ are eigenspace for largest and smallest eigenvalues respectively.

Comment: When you say $\vert A\vert_p$, do you mean $\max_{x:\Vert x\vert_p=1}\{\Vert Ax\Vert_p\}$ or do you mean $\left(\text{tr}(A^p)\right)^{1/p}$?  For the second (the Schatten $p$-norm) there is a general Holder inequality (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158881/h%C3%B6lders-inequality-for-matrices) and I think this could be used directly in your case (take $X=Y/\vert Y\vert_2$). For the first I'm not sure. But if you're thinking of the first, $\vert Y\vert_\infty$ isn't the same as it's maximum eigenvalue anyway, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to prove something that is false. Consider the operator
$$
Y = \begin{pmatrix} 
    2 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & -1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -1
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
In the case $p = 2$, the optimizer is $X_{\mathrm{opt},2} = Y/\sqrt{6}$, but for $p = 1$ we have
$$
X_{\mathrm{opt},1} = 
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
These optimizers are not related in the way you have expressed.

Let me point out a mistake in the second paragraph of the question, in case it is causing confusion: the maximum of $\operatorname{Tr}(XY)$ over all $X$ with $\|X\|_2 \leq 1$ is not equal to $\|X\|_1 \|Y\|_{\infty}$ in general. It is equal to $\|Y\|_2$, and the optimizer is $X = Y/\|Y\|_2$. You can prove this using Cauchy-Schwarz (for the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product).